# Apache Beam MinimalWordcount example with Dataflow Runner on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to run the MinimalWordCount example using the DataFlowRunner from Eclipse on windows using MinimalWordCount -->Run As Java Application from with in eclipse , its the same stock code from the example using my gcs bucket , however I consistently get the following exception , can some one let me know whats the issue here?

1. I have verified that the bucket name is correct.
2. I already ran the gcloud init on my Windows machine.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to
>   construct instance from factory method
>   DataflowRunner#fromOptions(interface
>   org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptions)
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:233)
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.build(InstanceBuilder.java:162)
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.PipelineRunner.fromOptions(PipelineRunner.java:56)
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.create(Pipeline.java:135)
>         at com.dynaobject.apachebeamexperiment.MinimalWordCount.main(MinimalWordCount.java:77)
>       Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.InstanceBuilder.buildFromMethod(InstanceBuilder.java:222)
>         ... 4 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DataflowRunner requires gcpTempLocation, but failed to retrieve a value from
>   PipelineOptions
>         at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:212)
>         ... 9 more
>       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Error constructing default value for gcpTempLocation: tempLocation is not a
>   valid GCS path, gs://tempxyz.** 
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:219)
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:205)
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.returnDefaultHelper(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:575)
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.getDefault(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:516)
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:155)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.getGcpTempLocation(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.DataflowRunner.fromOptions(DataflowRunner.java:210)
>         ... 9 more
>       **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Output path does not exist or is not writeable: gs://tempxyz**
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:191)
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsPathValidator.verifyPathIsAccessible(GcsPathValidator.java:78)
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.GcsPathValidator.validateOutputFilePrefixSupported(GcsPathValidator.java:62)
>         at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.GcpOptions$GcpTempLocationFactory.create(GcpOptions.java:217)
>         ... 15 more

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Somewhere in the documentation it was mentioned that I need to run the following .

> gcloud auth application-default login

Obviously the exception does not help with figuring out this , I hope it helps someone else.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks! I had to login and add the .json key file to my environment variable: 
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="XXX_credentials.json"